# Angular 2 & Typescript Observable Function Parameter - What Does Pipe Do?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

Recently I had a need to *take* an Observer parameter in a function, and I was banging my head on my desk trying to figure out how to do this in Typescript.  You might recall taking a `delegate` parameter in C#; that's basically what I was trying to do here.  This was part of a `subscribe(observer: Observer<any>)`.  The reason I was doing this is because I was trying to add an AOP type of bookend for subscriptions.  That's not the important part.

Basically to get this to work, you have to add a `|` character behind your function parameter, and it ends up like this:

`(observer: Observer<any>` **| ((value: any) => void)**`): void`

My question basically is what does the bold part do in that function signature?  I've scoured every resource I can think of but can't figure it out.  Without the portion after the `|`, I was getting this error:

> Argument of type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'Observer'. Property 'next' is missing in type '(res:
>   any) => void'.

Once I added the pipe character and portion after, I was able to subscribe without issue in the traditional observer way (using an arrow function), and I have also confirmed that all subscriptions work (which rules out the portion after the pipe being a default value).  Any ideas would be appreciated, because I hate seeing something work but having no idea why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the `observer` is of type `Observer<any>`

|(**or**)

`((value: any) => void)` : A function whose input is `any` value and output is `void`.

Comment: Also known as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) in typescript

Comment: Excellent!  It's completely obvious now.  The whole time I was thinking "pipe" because of Angular 2, not "OR" which is why I was having trouble with it.  Thanks tremendously!!

Comment: @CarlosMuentes Haha, no problem. Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 4):

as @echonax said: it means OR as @Rob said its a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

but I started writing this and I dont feel like throwing it away :), just because I'm slow. :)

1st you restricted yuor method to accept Observers

```
class SubscribeMe<T> {
    observable: Observable<T>;
    susbscribe(observer: Observer<T>){
        return observable.susbscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

then you tried to invoke it with an Action like signature 
    where Action is like

```
    type Action = <T>(t:T)=> void
```

by doing :

```
    susbscribeMe = new SubscribeMe<any>();
    susbscribeMe.susbscribe((x)=> console.log(x));
```

That doesn't match signature previously provided.

Then you added Action like signature to the method

```
 class SubscribeMe<T> {
    observabel: Observable<T>
    susbscribe(observer: Observer<T>| (x)=> void ){
        return observable.susbscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

or...

```
 class SubscribeMe<T> {
    observabel: Observable<T>
    susbscribe(observer: Observer<T>| Action<T>){
        return observable.susbscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

With that You told typescript you can call me with an Action Or With an Observer

... and finally this is all posible becasue Rx.Observable interface (rxjs/Observable.d.ts)

defines an overloaded signature for "subscribe" like the following

```
 *  subscribe(): Subscription;
 *  subscribe(observer: PartialObserver<T>): Subscription;
 *  subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

Which means you can subscribe with

- OR an Action
- OR an Observer
- Or Null/Nothing/Nada

but will always return a Subscription

ex:

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs";

export class SubscribeMe<T> {

    private _events = new Rx.Subject<T>();

    /** 
    * Hide the source of the observable  
    * */
    get events(): Rx.Observable<T> { return this._events.asObservable(); }

    /**
    *  Accept any signature accepted by Rx.Observabe INTERFACE (rxjs/Observable.d.ts)
    *  subscribe(): Subscription;
    *  subscribe(observer: PartialObserver<T>): Subscription;
    *  subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
    * 
    * as in OR Action<Ievent> Or Observer<Ievent> Or Null/Nothing/Nada
    */
    subscribe = (observer?: (e:T) => void | Rx.Observer<T>) => {
        return this.events.subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer - if I could accept both I would :)